# R Shiny - how to check query string at start of session

Tags: r, shiny, query-string

I have a shiny application in which the user can log into spotify. The way this works is that when pressing a button in my UI,
 the user get redirected to an official spotify login page, if they grant my app permission, spotify will then redirect them to

> https://username.shinyapp.io/myapp/?code=< authentication code >

I can then use that code later to access data etc.

My question is: *is there a way to save the querystring at the start of a shiny session?*

if the user has started the app (without logging in), the querystring will be empty. If the user is redirected no my app by spotify (which means they logged in) a new session is started, and the querystring will contain the code.
Therefore, it would be nice if i could save the querystring at the start of the session.

I thought of the code below. But getQueryString() can only be used in a reactive environment. 
I dont want to make the proces reactive however, because I dont want changes in the url during the session to affect the authorization process.

```
server <- function(input, output, session)
{
    code <- getQueryString()$code

    <rest of my code here>
}
```

Any thoughts on how to go about doing this? 
Thanks in advance!